# Testing implementation of '<T>' List

Tags: java, list, testing, collections

I have written my own implementation of java.utils.List. Now I'd like to test it, but I cannot manage to fill my collection with objects since it shows `<identifier> expected` whenever I add anything :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}

MyCollection col = new MyCollection(10);
int[] tab = {1,2,4,5,6};
col.add(tab);
```

And the whole code here :

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/291343/

---

EDIT

```
MyCollection<Integer> col = new MyCollection<Integer>(10);
Integer[] tab = {1,2,4,5,6};
col.add(tab);
```

still the same :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add an `int[]` as item of a `Collection<Integer>` which accepts `Integer` (or autoboxed `int`) items only. This would only work if you have a `Collection<int[]>` (of which the added array would then be the sole item).

To convert an `int[]` to a `Collection<Integer>`, you need to loop over it:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Collection<Integer> collection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int item : array) {
    collection.add(item);
}
```

#### See also:

- [Arrays tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [Collections tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)
- [Generics tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

Comment: This one's the correct one: Generics do not work with arrays, at least not in any useful way (*beyond varargs*).

Comment: @Esko: actually, varargs only works when it's an `Integer[]`. I removed the wrong answer hint :o

Comment: tried this one : http://paste.pocoo.org/show/291359/ and still "illegal start of type. ';' expected. `<identifier>` expected"

Comment: That thing apparently doesn't support enhanced for loop. Use a real Java IDE/editor. If you insist in using an online one, have a look at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/KgUAU). It runs fine there. However, I wouldn't recommend using it as real development tool.

Comment: guess my neatbeans crashed :/

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, sorry. Runs fine here in Eclipse. Maybe you've misconfigured your Netbeans project. Or it's just a misinterpretation of the error. To what line does it point?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your Type. It's a generic class, so it should be something like

```
MyCollection<Integer> col = new MyCollection<Integer>(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
MyCollection<Integer> col = new MyCollection<Interger>(10);
```

You need to specify the T of your MyCollection.

Answer (score 0):

The generic implications here would not cause an error, you would simply get a warning because any object you add to the list is erased to Object, so you could add any object and would lose type safety.

You have instantiated a list whose members are a single object, whatever the type may be, but you're trying to add an array as a single member.  You have a couple of options, but I would stick with:

```
List<Integer> myCollection = new MyCollection<Integer>(10);
myCollection.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
```

If you really intended on have a list of arrays, you would do:

```
List<Integer[]> myCollection = new MyCollection<Integer[]>(10);
myCollection.add(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

A couple of notes:

- Program to the interface (see my example)
- Your implementation is called `MyCollection`, but it's actually an implementation of List, so a name like `MyList` seems more appropriate unless you plan on actually extending `Collection`.
- I assume this is just an exercise, but I don't see the point in extending `List`.  You know that `java.util.ArrayList` exists right?